# How can I use the predictive experiment of Azure ML on my website

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I used Azure ML studio and I obtained a predictive experiment with an API key.

**My question is:**
How can I embed this API key or the text obtained or the predictive experiment on a website or on my portfolio?
So that others can use the predictive experiment from the website...